# Exposing different view of Class

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

Is it possible to give different view of a Class . For example , i have Account class , i want expose this data using WCF. For different method call i want expose different property of Account class.Suppose for particular call i want expose only UserName and Password, for
another call i want expose Email and Address. Should i have to write different class or 
i can expose needed property to client

Comment: Why would you want to hide certain properties when calling certain methods? Is it to hide it from programmers or from users?

Comment: @Heki - from the mention of [wcf] and [web-services], we should probably infer that the data a **client** needs is not necessarily the same as the data the system needs internally.

Comment: You're probably right, but I felt the need to ask a clarifying question. Anyway, I would definitely go with the DTOs like you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If *one* usage is WCF and *another* usage is internal to your app, then you can annotate the class appropriately with `[DataMember]` such that only the desired properties are exposed. If you have two different WCF scenarios, then I would introduce a new class (or classes) to represent each set of return data, probably adding an implicit [conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) (from the *entity* to the *DTO*), so that you can do:

```
public CustomerLite GetCustomer(int id) {
    Customer cust = SomeTier.GetCustomer(id);
    return cust; // note cust is Customer but we are returning CustomerLite
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using interfaces as "views". For example create a UsernamePassword interface with methods or properties to access username and password and have the Account class implement this interface. You can then pass this interface around and the users of it will be unaware of the other methods and properties in the account class.

```
  interface IUsernamePassword
  {
    string Username { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
  }

  class Account : IUsernamePassword
  {
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Note there is WCF in here too, which can impact things; also, it may or may-not matter that the caller could cast away the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a DataContract with DataMember attributes, but that allows you to produce only one serialised view of a class. You would probably want to create smaller ViewModel classes, possibly using AutoMapper to handle all the mapping code for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expose multiple views of the same `Account` class, the answer is no (that I'm aware of).  Using the default `DataContractSerializer`, you can control which members are presented to the user only in a declarative manner.  This would allow you to customize the user's view in one way, but not multiples.

Instead, you can create one individual data contract class (which might take an `Account` as a constructor argument) for each "view" you wish to expose.

Answer (score 0):

Always, always, always use a message class (aka DTO) when using any service that is hosted outside of your app domain.

I use to have a slide in all my presentations on WCF that stated Message Classes != Business Classes, but I've since found a better way to explain it.

This isn't Star Trek people.  [You Can't Fax a Cat](http://franksworld.com/blog/archive/2010/06/30/12031.aspx) (a picture is worth a 1000 words).